# AngularJS Wordpress JSON API Plugin returning html instead of json

Tags: javascript, angularjs, wordpress, http-get, wordpress-json-api

I'm trying to get recent posts from my wordpress blog but it's returning html instead of json. I want to use json to make it easier to access the blog contents. I already have the plugin installed and activated. Here's what I do to get the posts:

```
  $http.get('blog/?json=get_recent_posts')
  .success(function(data, status, headers, config){
      $scope.post = data;
      console.log(data);
  })
  .error(function(data, status, headers, config){-
      console.log("unable to access!!!!!!!!!!!");
  });
```

What's the reason that it's returning html instead of json? Are there any workarounds? Some other posts mentioned using jsonp but that did not work for me either.

Answer (score 0):

I'm likely doing it wrong, but when I form my requests for a Wordpress installation at `http://www.example.com/` like this:

`http://www.example.com/index.php?rest_route=/my/rest/route/here`

I end up getting proper responses back.

I had a heck of a time figuring this out and ended up grokking a URL formatted like that in the HTML returned to me. I was expecting to make requests as `http://www.example.com/wp_json/wp/v2/my/rest/route/here` , but I only got HTML responses.